# Will ARC tell me when I must use __block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, automatic-ref-counting

AFAIK, `__block` is used when you're changing, inside the block, the address that a variable (declared outside the block) points to.

But, what if I'm changing the value that the variable points to but the pointer stays the same? E.g., what if I have `NSMutableArray *array` and am just doing `[array addObject:object]` inside the block? In this case, I'm not changing the pointer `array`, but I'm changing the value it points to. So, must I still use `__block` in declaring `NSMutableArray *array`?

Answer (score 19):

You only need `__block` if you are changing the value of the variable.

I.e. if you have:

```
NSArray* foo;
```

You only need `__block` if you change the value of `foo`.  Now, keep in mind that `foo` is nothing more than "a pointer to a thing that is typed `NSArray`".   I.e.  `foo` is effectively a 64 bit or 32 bit integer, depending on platform.  If you change that integer, you need `__block`.  If you don't, you don't need `__block`.

So, no, you don't need `__block` to call `addObject:` on the array since you aren't actually changing the value of `foo`.

If you were to do something like `foo = (expression);`, then you'd need `__block`.

(note that this is one of the reasons why concurrent programming under OO is so damned hard... it is exceptionally hard to define the "domain of variance" for any given execution path)

Comment: What about compiler optimization? `__block` might hint it that an object never changes, and if `NSArray` was inlined, subsequent calls to capacity might have been wrong.

Comment: `__block` indicates that the variable can change.  Whether or not the variable is `__block` or a const-copy (as is the default), calling a method on the object will not be impacted.

Comment: But what happens if the variable (NSArray *) is a self property ? Does the __block need to be added ?

Comment: If you are using `self.foo = ...;` then, no, no `__block` is needed because that is a method call.  Nor would it be needed to modify the instance variable directly (since the reference to the ivar is through self).